# Mockito claiming method called twice

Tags: java, mockito

I am running a test on my class using Mockito. The test verifies that a method called postMessage(destination, messageString) is called.

My test aims to verify that, depending on the message content, postMessage() is either called once or zero times.

The issue I have is that in my class, I have 2 calls to postMessage(). The difference between the 2 calls is the destination - the calls send a message to 2 different destinations.

e.g.

```
1. postMessage(destination-1, message)

2. postMessage(destination-2, message)
```

When I call verify with 1 times, like so

```
//actually called twice because of destination-1 and destination-2
verify(sender, times(1)).postMessage(Mockito.<javax.jms.Destination>.any(), Mockito.<String>.any());
```

the actual number is 2. I know the number 2 is right because it's called twice, but I want to isolate a test on only the method called with destination-2.

Also, when I want to verify that postMessage() is called zero times (message not sent), my test will class will rightly claim that postMessage() was called once - this is because it was actually called for destination-1.

```
//actually called once because of destination-1
verify(sender, times(0)).postMessage(Mockito.<javax.jms.Destination>.any(), Mockito.<String>.any());
```

So my question is - how do I isolate my test to testing exactly what I want and not the behaviour of my first call to postMessage()?

Comment: What is ``destination-1``/``2``? Seems to be an integer for me...

Comment: Why do you use `Mockito.<javax.jms.Destination>.any()` if you don't want to match _any_ Destination? Use `eq(destXYZ)` instead with "destXYZ" being your destination to test.

Comment: How about splitting the method that calls `postMessage` for destination-1 and destination-2 into two separate methods. Then test each method's call count separately.

Comment: @TomMac How about avoiding code duplication ;P? The method `postMessage` is fine as it is.

Comment: @Tom how do I say your answer worked?

Comment: What? Either your test worked, or not.

Comment: @Tom I used your suggestion and the test now passes. I want to highlight that your suggestion is the correct answer so tat others can see the solution. It's good practice to do this. It shares knowledge.

Comment: Oh that's what you meant. Creating an answer to explain how you solved the problem, for example by following a suggestion from a comment, is correct, so you've done everything right :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @Tom's suggestion: 
Why do you use Mockito..any() if you don't want to match any Destination? Use eq(destXYZ) instead with "destXYZ" being your destination to test.

Replacing:

```
//actually called twice because of destination-1 and destination-2
verify(sender, times(1)).postMessage(Mockito.<Destination>.any(), Mockito.<String>.any());
```

with

```
Destination myDest = mock(Destination.class);

//actually called twice because of destination-1 and destination-2
verify(sender, times(1)).postMessage(myDest, Mockito.<String>.any());
worked.
```

passed my test.